# What does a grayed-out user name mean?

Tags: discussion

The OP user block on [this recent question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/59288/what-type-of-angel-was-the-morning-star) is grayed out.  I've not seen that before.  Does this mean the OP made an account, posted a question, and then deleted the account?

Comment: For future reference, all site functions have been covered on https://meta.stackexchange.com/. You can search there next time and get a faster answer.

Comment: Thanks @fredsbend!  I didn't even think of going there to search.  I just searched here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That question was migrated from a site where the OP does have an account.  If he or she chooses to register here it'll be un-grayed out.

No registration = nothing to click on.

If the account was deleted it would go back to user4393949.

Comment: Ah-hah.  Thanks!